# ssh stale? not doing anything

Tags: mac, ssh

My `ssh` isn't working properly. When I perform the following command, nothing happens. The cursor doesn't go the next line to accept a password and  I don't get an error. No hang either. It just moves to the next line waiting for another command.

```
$ ssh username@foo.edu
$
```

The following is what I've done to troubleshoot.

1. Tried the verbose option. But same result.

   ```
   $ ssh -v username@foo.edu
   $
   ```
2. Tried pinging the location. It seems I can get to it.

   ```
   $ ping foo.edu
   PING foo.edu (10.50.178.250): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=4.369 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=3.013 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=3.235 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=2.791 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=10.105 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=5 ttl=60 time=4.321 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=6 ttl=60 time=2.754 ms
   64 bytes from 10.50.178.250: icmp_seq=7 ttl=60 time=2.801 ms
   ^C
   --- foo.edu ping statistics ---
   8 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.754/4.174/10.105/2.326 ms
   ```
3. Restarted computer. No change.
4. Restarted ssh service (I'm on a Mac) No change.

   ```
   $ sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
   $ sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
   ```
5. manned it for the hell of it. Got the manual.

   ```
   $ man ssh
   ```
6. checked to see if ssh was actually in `/usr/bin`. Yep it's there.

   ```
   $ ll /usr/bin | grep ssh
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     3B Oct 21  2016 slogin -> ssh
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   2.0M Apr 28  2017 ssh
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   1.7M Apr 28  2017 ssh-add
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   1.7M Apr 28  2017 ssh-agent
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel    10K Nov 14  2016 ssh-copy-id
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   1.8M Apr 28  2017 ssh-keygen
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   1.8M Apr 28  2017 ssh-keyscan
   ```
7. Ran the following.

   ```
   $ type ssh
   ssh is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ssh)
   $ vim /usr/local/bin/ssh
   1#!/bin/sh
   2
   3 HOSTNAME=$@
   ```

I can't seem to figure out what is happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does `type ssh` return?

Comment: ssh is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ssh). What does this mean?

Comment: It works when I do /usr/bin/ssh username@foo.edu it works! So, I must have rerouted this baby. Looking into it now.

Comment: I've been trying to use the proper formatting, but the code{} option isn't working and neither is the 4 space indent. the admin edited out my comment about this. It worked the first few times I used it, but then stopped.

Comment: I know, I did this; any user (with enough reputation) could. You just need more spaces when inside numbered list.

Comment: got it. and edited. thanks. didn't realize it had turned to a numbered list format, even though that's what I was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `/usr/bin/ssh` your shell runs `/usr/local/bin/ssh` which is a script that does nothing.

This is probably because `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`. Nothing wrong with this; it's the script that's the issue.

**If you have `sudo` access** then you can remove the script (in general it will affect all users; it's worth investigating why the script is there in the first place; the script is weird, so removing it will probably be the right thing anyway):

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ssh
```

Additionally you need to tell your shell to forget the now obsolete path to `ssh`:

```
hash -d ssh
```

**Without `sudo` access** you can circumvent this weird script with an alias:

```
alias ssh=/usr/bin/ssh
```